# minimum value of a trigonometric equation is given. the problem is when the minimum value attains

Tags: geometry, analysis, trigonometry

Suppose the minimum value of $\cos^{2}(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})+\cos^{2}(\theta_{2}-\theta_{3})+\cos^{2}(\theta_{3}-\theta_{1})$ is $\frac{3}{4}$.
Also the following equations are given
$$\cos^{2}(\theta_{1})+\cos^{2}(\theta_{2})+\cos^{2}(\theta_{3})=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\sin^{2}(\theta_{1})+\sin^{2}(\theta_{2})+\sin^{2}(\theta_{3})=\frac{3}{2}$$ and
$$\cos\theta_{1}\sin\theta_{1}+\cos\theta_{2}\sin\theta_{2}+\cos\theta_{3}\sin\theta_{3}=0$$
To my intuition it can be proved that the minimum value of the 1st expression attains only if $(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})=(\theta_{2}-\theta_{3})=(\theta_{3}-\theta_{1})=\frac{\pi}{3}$.
Provide some hints and techniques how to solve this.

Comment: It is known that the minimum value of $\cos^{2}(\theta_{1}-\theta_{2})+\cos^{2}(\theta_{2}-\theta_{3})+\cos^{2}(\theta_{3}-\theta_{1})$ is $\frac{3}{4}$. It is also known that the minimum value is attained iff the vectors $(\cos\theta_{1},\sin\theta_{1}), (\cos\theta_{2},\sin\theta_{2}), (\cos\theta_{3},\sin\theta_{3})$ forms vertices of a equilateral traingle. But i cannot prove this. Any other technique will be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x,$

$$\cos\theta_1\sin\theta_1+\cos\theta_2\sin\theta_2+\cos\theta_3\sin\theta_3=0$$
$$\implies \sin2\theta_1+\sin2\theta_2+\sin2\theta_3=0$$
$$\implies \sin2\theta_1+\sin2\theta_2=-\sin2\theta_3\ \ \ \ (1)$$

As $\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x,$

$$\cos^2\theta_1+\cos^2\theta_2+\cos^2\theta_3=\frac32=\sin^2\theta_1+\sin^2\theta_2+\sin^2\theta_3$$
$$\implies  \cos2\theta_1+\cos2\theta_2+\cos2\theta_3=0$$
$$\implies \cos2\theta_1+\cos2\theta_2=-\cos2\theta_3\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Squaring & adding $(1),(2)$

$$\sin^22\theta_1+\sin^22\theta_2+2\sin2\theta_1\sin2\theta_2+(\cos^22\theta_1+\cos^22\theta_2+2\cos2\theta_1\cos2\theta_2)=\sin^22\theta_3+\cos^22\theta_3$$

$$\implies 2+2\cos2(\theta_1-\theta_2)=1$$

Using $\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1,$

$$2+ 2\left(2\cos^2(\theta_1-\theta_2)-1\right)=1\implies \cos^2(\theta_1-\theta_2)=\frac14$$

Similarly, $\theta_2-\theta_3,\theta_3-\theta_1$